# .change(function() changing whenever a <select> has input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have three divs

first div has 3 text box's with `.change` whenever input is typed in, works fine

second div has 2 date select inputs works fine moves to next on input.

The problem i am running into here is that i have added a `<select>` form and it has 6 options but I cant find a way to make it `.change` whenever the select form has been modified is `.change` able to do this or is there some other way?

here is my js I know its sloppy

```
$("#areyourfrom,#areyourgoing").change(function() {
  if ($("#areyourfrom").val() != '' && $("#areyourgoing").val() != '') {
    $('.when input').attr('disabled', 0);
    $('.when img.whenImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/when.png');
    $('.where img.whereimage').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/where02.png');
    $("#date02").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#date01").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#flexibleDates").attr("disabled", false);
    $('.when .line').addClass('active');
    $('.when .info').addClass('active');
    $('.where .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.where .info').removeClass('active');
  }
  $("a[href*='where']").add('.where input').click(function() {
    $('.where .line').addClass('active');
    $('.where .info').addClass('active');
    $('.where img.whereimage').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/where.png');
    $('.when img.whenImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/when02.png');
    $('.who img.whoImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/who02.png');
    $("#date02").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#date01").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#flexibleDates").attr("disabled", false);
    $('.when .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.when .info').removeClass('active');
    $('.who .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.who .info').removeClass('active');
  })
  $("a[href*='when']").add('.when input').click(function() {
    $('.when img.whenImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/when.png');
    $('.where img.whereimage').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/where02.png');
    $('.who img.whoImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/who02.png');
    $('.when .line').addClass('active');
    $('.when .info').addClass('active');
    $('.who .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.who .info').removeClass('active');
    $('.where .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.where .info').removeClass('active');
  })
})

$("#date01,#date02").change(function() {
  if ($("#date01").val() != '' && $("#date02").val() != '') {
    $('.who input').attr('disabled', 0);
    $('.who img.whoImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/who.png');
    $('.when img.whenImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/when02.png');
    $("#howmanyadults").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#howmanychildren").attr("disabled", false);
    $('.who .line').addClass('active');
    $('.who .info').addClass('active');
    $('.when .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.when .info').removeClass('active');
    $('#submit').show();
  }
  $("a[href*='where']").add('.where input').click(function() {
    $('.where img.whereimage').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/where.png');
    $('.when img.whenImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/when02.png');
    $('.who img.whoImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/who02.png');
    $("#date02").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#date01").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#flexibleDates").attr("disabled", false);
    $('.where .line').addClass('active');
    $('.where .info').addClass('active');
    $('.when .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.when .info').removeClass('active');
    $('.who .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.who .info').removeClass('active');
  })
  $("a[href*='when']").add('.when input').click(function() {
    $('.when img.whenImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/when.png');
    $('.where img.whereimage').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/where02.png');
    $('.who img.whoImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/who02.png');
    $('.when .line').addClass('active');
    $('.when .info').addClass('active');
    $('.who .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.who .info').removeClass('active');
    $('.where .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.where .info').removeClass('active');
  })
  $("a[href*='who']").add('.who input').click(function() {
    $('.when img.whenImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/when02.png');
    $('.where img.whereimage').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/where02.png');
    $('.who img.whoImg').attr('src', '<?php echo $host;?>/images/who.png');
    $('.who .line').addClass('active');
    $('.who .info').addClass('active');
    $('.when .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.when .info').removeClass('active');
    $('.where .line').removeClass('active');
    $('.where .info').removeClass('active');
  })
})

$("#howmanyadults").change(function() {
  if ($("#howmanyadults").val() != '') {
    $('#submit').show().attr("disabled", false);
  }
})
```

Comment: .click is for links that i have on top of each div sorry for not clarifying

Comment: you should probably pair this down to a small sizable, readable format and maybe include a jsfiddle so we don't have to try to reproduce this.  As of now your question probably won't get an answer because it is unreadable for the most part

Comment: Also a pretty terrible but functioning jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0ebccy6y/

Comment: A jsfiddle would be extremely helpful here

Comment: GL with that one @CaseyRule :/

Comment: It is extremely unclear what your question is, Tyler.  Could you be more specific about what your problem is?  It would be helpful if you could create a minimal example that displays the problem you are experiencing, with all the extra stuff stripped out.  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try this one instead http://jsfiddle.net/0ebccy6y/2/

Comment: ok ill see what i can do and remove extra stuff what im trying to do is if you look at the fiddle it will .change to the final div whenever you have input for the date values without letting you get a chance to edit the select dropdown

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ebccy6y/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finnally figured it out i just had to add the select box to my current code

```
    $("#date01,#date02,#flexibleDates").change(function() {
  if ($("#date01").val() != '' && $("#date02").val() != '' && $("#flexibleDates").val() != '') {
```

`#flexibleDates` being the `<select>` that i was talking about it now wait for a user to select something in the dropdown and once something is selected continues to the next step

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead... Much cleaner, works better, and is easier to use and understand.

**Even better:** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/s4yr1ju9/

**More functionality:** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/s4yr1ju9/3/show

**Simpler Which i like:** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/s4yr1ju9/1/

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/t56k8pho/

Total js code:

```
$('.when input').datepicker();
$('.where label:first-of-type input').focus();
```

Comment: Yes this is cleaner but it is not doing what i need, i have the change function so that whenever someone has input made on step one it will automatically go to step 2 and disable step one my problem is on step two `.change` will not recognise whenever a `.change` has been made to my `<select>` therefore it will not continue

Comment: i see, but isn't a bad ui design to Block Previous Ui element. Why do you want it to be disabled.

Comment: but you won't know if they are done...lets say i am typing city, abc and there is city ab. Js would think i am done at ab and take me to next step. When i am not. Samething with options, if i am trying to do 6 days of flexibility but i am using keyboard to go through list after every  choice is the valid choice and thus input is made. Valid but not correct as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: everything is set to autocomplete right now, for city and country i have a iataa list and whenever user types what they want it will autofill i have a `.click` function that allows the user to go back and edit there input whenever they click on the previous input

Comment: that site is doing exactly what i am doing...you can put a list in the example i gave. http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

Comment: That is actually really awesome and way better than having a list from airport codes which is what im doing currently but unfortuntly im located in china and google is blocked:(

Comment: i do:) whenever your website needs to work in china its not really a option to use google, yea  bing still works